# Can we connect amazon redshift thro linux shellscript without password?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Team, 
I am using amazon redshift ( 8.0.2. ). While connect redshift cluster, we can connect without password ( this setting we can do in my local machine - pg_hba.conf entry ).But
I have set "md5" to prompt password.

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
#host    postgres   postgres    <my_ip>      md5
```

Now i would like to connect redshift thro linux server. in my shell script, I am connecting redshift and doing my activities. But I should be able to connect redhsift (i.e i shold be able to pass the password as variable, and after connect, i should be able to perform my activities ).

Could you please guide me on this ?

Thaks

Answer (score 2):

Try using the below, it worked for me.

```
psql "host=yourhostname port=yourport_no dbname=your_DB_name user=your_user_id password=your_password" -F  --no-align    -c  " Your_SQL_statement"
```

Comment: Commenting on this , how can I connect and then access the data from it . So first I give the connection and then how do I acess the sql?

Answer (score 0):

If I have not misunderstood you, you want to avoid being asked for your password by the terminal. If this is so, you can do it by using the environment variable "PGPASSWORD" in order to give your password to redshift.

Then you can use "-w"  (in lowercase with nothing else) in your comand line to avoid asking the password.

Something like that:

```
export PGPASSWORD=your_password
psql -h your_hostname -d your_databae -U your_user -p your_port -w
```